# boolean getters using xjc and ant

Tags: ant, cxf, xjc

I am working on a project which uses xjc to generate the java files from XSD. 
The problem I am facing is it generate Boolean getters as isXXX instead of getXXX.

```
<target name="jaxb">
    <delete dir="${generated-src}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${generated-src}"/>
    <xjc destdir="${generated-src}" extension="true">
        <schema dir="${schema-source}" includes="*.xsd"/>
        <binding dir="${schema-source}" includes="*.xjb"/>


    </xjc>
</target>
```

Providing args such as 
     
or
     
gives error 
Caused by: com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException: unrecognized parameter -enableIntrospection
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArguments(Options.java:762)

I see maven plugin CXF XJC Boolean Getter Plugin but I am not sure how to use this with ant. 
I am using jaxb-impl -2.1.12 and jaxb-xjc- 2.1.12.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

refer to: https://jaxb.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=631.
jaxb-xjc-2.1.12 fixed this issue but only effect on jaxb 2.2 or later version.

but if you use jaxb-xjc-2.2.5, parameter "-enableIntrospection" works for this issue.

but for CXF XJC Boolean Getter Plugin, I have no idea. it should works when you use commandline.

I met the same problem when I use DynamicClientFactory, I found there is no way to set parameter enableIntrospection or CXF XJC Boolean Getter Plugin.